# How to turn curl command into python equivalent?

Tags: python, python-requests, telegram-bot

I'm trying to implement a python script which will set a webhook with the [`setWebhook`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) method of telegram bot api. As it is explained [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#how-do-i-set-a-webhook-for-either-type) after creating a self-signed certificate we can achieve this with this curl command:

```
curl -F "url=https://<YOURDOMAIN.EXAMPLE>/<WEBHOOKLOCATION>" \
-F "certificate=@<YOURCERTIFICATE>.pem" https://api.telegram.org/bot<YOURTOKEN>/setWebhook
```

Calling **this curl command** set the webhook **without any problem** and I get updates through it.

**But now** I'm trying to achieve this with the python script so I could just call it with some command line arguments so it set webhook for me, get info about it or delete it. What I wrote so far is this:

```
files = {
        'file': ('certificate', open(configuration.CERTFILE, 'rb'))
    }

headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}

data = {
        'url': configuration.WEBHOOK_URL,
    }

url = configuration.API % 'setWebhook'
rp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, files=files)

print('result of setWebhook: ', rp.status_code)
```

The status code of **the response is** `400 Bad Request`. I think that I'm sending the request the wrong way.

Any ideas about **what is wrong** with my `requests` request to telegram bot api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `headers` parameter and renaming the key of the `files` parameter did the trick. So, now my code looks like this:

```
files = {
    'certificate': ('certificate', open(configuration.CERTFILE, 'rb'))
}

data = {
    'url': configuration.WEBHOOK_URL,
}

url = configuration.API % 'setWebhook'
rp = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact curl query taking two file parameters `-F` can be converted into `python-requests` into

```
import requests

files = {
    'url': 'https://<YOURDOMAIN.EXAMPLE>/<WEBHOOKLOCATION>',
    'certificate': open('<YOURCERTIFICATE>.pem', 'rb')
}

requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/bot<YOURTOKEN>/setWebhook', files=files)
```

Comment: `curl -h` says that `-F` *Specify HTTP multipart POST data* and `url` is not a file. Anyways I have tried the code you've provided but without any success.